# Permutations of the same 4 digits resulting into 2 pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get the permutations in for below 4 numbers with only 2 results.
Expected pair is [4,4] and [4,4]

```
4,4,4,4
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
xnor  -1  pair is  (4, 4)
Total Pairs 12
```

Here is the program which I wrote.

```
from itertools import permutations

userInput = input("Please enter comma separated numbers : \n")

inputArray = [int(e) if e.isdigit() else e for e in userInput.split(',')]

result = permutations(inputArray, 2)
count = 0
for pair in list(result):
    xNor = ~(pair[0] ^ pair[1])
    if xNor == -1:
        print("xnor ", xNor, " pair is ", pair)
        count = count + 1

print("Total Pairs", count)
```

Modification
This is one of the question i was asked during an interview.
Appreciate any hint or solution.

[image]

Comment: Why is the expected output only two pairs?

Comment: Expectation is pairs should not intersect.

Comment: Basically dont want to use bruit force

Comment: What do you mean by "pairs should not intersect"? Can you explain better what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: I can think of getting the unique numbers and their count in directory but i am not sure how the pairs are getting generated over here.

Comment: What is the definition of XNOR?  A bit wise XNOR will return True if all bits are False or all bits are True.  How does this work for integers?

Comment: Xnor = ~(n1 ^ n2) is giving the correct result for given input and output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually using a brute-force approach, which is O(n!). Here's a O(n²) approach:

```py
def xnor_pairs(seq):
    # Create two pointers: one on the start and another at the end
    i0 = 0
    i1 = len(seq) - 1
    
    pairs = []
    
    # Repeat this until the start pointer has not reached the end
    while i0 < len(seq) - 1:
        a, b = seq[i0], seq[i1]
        
        # If the start and end indexes are equal
        if i0 == i1:
            # Move the start pointer one position closer to the end
            i0 += 1
            # Move the end pointer back to the end
            i1 = len(seq) - 1
            
            continue

        # If the condition is satisfied (a XNOR b == -1)
        if ~(a ^ b) == -1:
            # Append to the pairs
            pairs.append((a, b))
        
        # Move the end pointer one position closer to the start
        i1 -= 1
        
    return pairs

print(xnor_pairs([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 10, 10, 10]))
# Output: [(3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 4), (4, 4), (10, 10), (10, 10), (10, 10)]
```